# Is there a way to see the individual filename for "Falling back to direct application" lines while doing a git threeway patch application?

Tags: git

I just ran a git threeway patch apply, which I quite often do, here's the (partly redacted) output:

```
C:\nma\Repositories\myapp-android>git apply --3way ..\newbuildtype.patch
Applied patch to 'app/build.gradle' cleanly.
Applied patch to 'app/src/androidTest/java/com/mycompany/myapp/ui/fragments/jobs/MyTest.kt' cleanly.
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Falling back to direct application...
Applied patch to 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' cleanly.
Applied patch to 'app/src/test/java/com/mycompany/myapp/ui/custom_components/MyTest.java' cleanly.
Applied patch to 'coverage/app-jacoco.gradle' cleanly.
Applied patch to 'coverage/sonar-properties.gradle' cleanly.
Applied patch to 'mylib/build.gradle' cleanly.

C:\nma\Repositories\myapp-android>
```

Is there any way to get git to tell me the file name for each of the "Falling back to direct application" lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code ([apply.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bda494f4043963b9ec9a1ecd4b19b7d1cd9a0518/apply.c#L3701-L3709)), there does not seem to be any message shown when the code falls back to direct application and succeeds (`apply_fragment`  does show an error if direct application fails).

So you would need something like this:

```
diff --git a/apply.c b/apply.c
index 3d69fec836..edfa82e451 100644
--- a/apply.c
+++ b/apply.c
@@ -3704,8 +3704,13 @@ static int apply_data(struct apply_state *state, struct patch *patch,
            fprintf(stderr, _("Falling back to direct application...\n"));
 
        /* Note: with --reject, apply_fragments() returns 0 */
-       if (patch->direct_to_threeway || apply_fragments(state, &image, patch) < 0)
+       if (patch->direct_to_threeway || apply_fragments(state, &image, patch) < 0) {
            return -1;
+       } else {
+           if (state->apply_verbosity > verbosity_silent)
+               fprintf(stderr, _("Applied patch to '%s' cleanly.\n",
+                       patch->new_name));
+       }
    }
    patch->result = image.buf;
    patch->resultsize = image.len;
```

I encourage you to submit a similar change if think it's worth it:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/SubmittingPatches
- https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md